# Purpose of @Named in Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints

It's not clear to me what @Named is used for in Google Cloud Endpoints.  The documentation says:

> This annotation indicates the name of the parameter in the request
> that gets injected here. A parameter that is not annotated with @Named
> is injected with the whole request object. ... This sample shows the
> use of @Named:
>
> ```
>  @ApiMethod(
>    name = "foos.remove",
>    path = "foos/{id}",
>    httpMethod = HttpMethod.DELETE)   
> public void removeFoo(@Named("id") String id){}
> ```
>
> where @Named specifies that only the id parameter is injected in the
> request.

If @Named was not used in this example, what instead is "injected"? with the "whole request"? For that matter, what exactly is "injected"? And what is the "whole request"? Does the @Named object always have to be part of the path defined in @Apimethod?

Thanks.

Comment: Documentation is a bit sparse. To me, this reads like you can have a parameter of type HttpServletRequest and get that injected. Or use @Named to get individual parameters as a String (and maybe as an Integer, too?). More examples would not have hurt...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**: although my answer below is not really wrong, it's not complete at all. Basically when you add `@Named` annotation, the parameters will be included at the end of the request URL:

```
http://endpointurl?parameter1=xxx&parameter2=yyy
```

If you don't use `@Named`, the parameter will be included (*injected*) within the POST data. You can see it very clear by creating a test endpoint with some named parameters and some unnamed ones, and using some request explorer tool such as Firebug.

Obviously the parameter types that support `@Named` annotation are only a few (int, long, String, Boolean and their correspondent arrays, I think).

What I said in my original answer below isn't false, but is not a complete answer...

---

**Original answer**: As far as I understand, the purpose of @Named is to indicate the name of the parameter in the request URL. This way a parameter can have a name within your app and other name exposed in the endpoint.

It's pretty much the same that @SerializedName in GSON or @Column in JDO. All these annotations allow to have 2 different names for your parameters, one in your app, following Java naming conventions, and another name following other conventions such as URL or JSON ones...

In your example you can't note the difference, but you can have this method:

```
@ApiMethod(
  name = "remove",
  path = "remove",
  httpMethod = HttpMethod.DELETE) 
public void removeFoo(@Named("my_app_id") String myAppID){}
```

In this case the name of the parameter in the URL would be:

```
https://mygaeappid.appspot.com/_ah/api/yourapi/v1/remove?my_app_id=1234
```

And no, the @Named object doesn't always have to be part of the path defined in ApiMethod.

Comment: Thanks MikO, this is helpful.  Do you have a comment on this aspect of the question:  "A parameter that is not annotated with @Named is injected with the whole request object"

Comment: Thanks for the update MikO, this makes sense.  Finally, though, who cares if the parameter is injected with the POST data?  What difference does it make?

Comment: Well, for example if you want to send a parameter of a complex type (anything but a string, int, long, boolean,...) you need to send it in the POST data... Furthermore, there exist differences between HTTP GET and POST in general that can make one method more suitable than the other for concrete cases...

Comment: How can I send the named parameter on post request body.  My request body contains named parameter as well as a entity. Is it possible??